# vb6 - create html document in runtime + set baseurl

Tags: html, vb6, document

i'm creating a htmlfile like this:

```
Dim m_doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set obj = CreateObject("htmlfile")
obj.Open
obj.Write m_htm
Set m_doc = obj
```

the variable m_htm contains plain html data.
my problem: the created htmldocument will have local paths for links/includes.
how can i set the document's baseUrl?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `<base>` tag within the `<head>` section of your HTML data.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp

Comment: i found out that using .write only sets the actual body data, there's no head! do u know how to also the head data?

Comment: Try finding it in the All collection.